# Serenity Reports Logo Change

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity with Jbehave. I would like to know how to replace the current report's default logo of serenity with a custom company logo. what is code changes need to be done for changing the default logo?

Comment: Hi,

Did you got a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by replacing the *serenity-bdd-logo.png* in *serenity-report-resources-x.x.xx.jar*. Save your logo and name it likewise, then copy and overwrite the existing one. Mine is stored in the following location:

> serenity-report-resources-x.x.xx.jar\report-resources\images\

This should work for any project running on your machine and using that single jar file. It is made easier with Maven as it stores all downloaded dependencies in one location.

Otherwise, I doubt there is any legitimate way to perform this trick. You can write Java code to rename your logo and copy it to reports location each time you run serenity reports, but all that are just hacks really :)

Serenity reports are built out of FreeMaket Template Language (.ftl) files stored in *serenity-report-resources-x.x.xx.jar* (another possible solution is to overwrite these and reference your own file each time *serenity-bdd-logo.png* is mentioned). Ideally you would want to create your own jar and force serenity to use this one. However, that seems a lot work just to replace a logo. Makes sense if you want to overhaul the whole look and feel of the reports.